# django Exception KeyError in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored

Tags: python, django

Recently I added a logging mechanism to my django application 1.3 using the following setting

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'debug':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': base('logs/app_log/developer.debug.log') if ENV ==1 else base('../../logs/app_log/developer.debug.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'mz.debug': {
            'handlers': ['debug'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

this settings works perfectly on my local machine but once I deploy to the server the get the following error

```
[Sun Jul 24 06:37:04 2011] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1218405744,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

when I remove the logging settings from the server it works fine. I don't know what in my settings that drives the server to return such an error and how would I solve this? many thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Exception+KeyError%3A+KeyError%22+threading)

[First hit](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=197)

Update mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Apache's mod_wsgi to 3.3. I use Ubuntu 10.04, and as of this writing, the package hasn't been updated. So I [built from source](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list). Make sure to disable mod_wsgi before you install the newer version 3.3. I didn't do this and my Apache crashed with error:

```
seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

Comment: That would be a different issue to what the question is about.